# How can I fix "python version are always returned 2.7 instead of 3.7"

Tags: python

I downloaded Python 3.7.3, but Python 2.7.10 already existed.

Now `python --version` returns 2.7.10.

How can I fix this?

Comment: What about `python3 --version` ?

Comment: You lack an operating system tag, but sounds like you are on a UNIX-like system, and the default version on these is usually Python 2. `python` is link to `python2`. If you want to run Python 3 you have to explicitly run `python3`. If you want to change the default for the system (which is not recommended at all!) you have to `update-alternatives` or something similar.

Comment: You downloaded it *how* and you have installed it *where*?

Comment: I'm voting this question up, because although it's vague, it's linked to by other questions that such as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69612874/i-install-python-3-10-0-and-in-command-prompt-show-me-version-2-7-2 and it asks a critical question, namely that sometimes when you install python the apt-get package manager installs it, and it's just simply not there. Additionally, there's a step required under linux to add the new python version to the python config tool and select the version of python used. See my answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are working on Linux, you can always type `python3 --version` to check if it is installed and be sure it is the version you want to use.

There are several ways to make `python` call Python 3 by default. For instance you can create an alias. Type `whereis python3` so you get the installation path to `python3` (normally it is located in `/usr/bin/python3`). If that's the case you can simply add to `~/.bashrc` the following line:

```
alias python='/usr/bin/python3'
```

Then, `source` that file or reload the session. This assumes that `/usr/bin/python3` is the location of Python 3. Please, note that other commands that depend on your Python installation (such as `pip` or `coverage`) are still pointing to the ones installed by Python 2, so you may want to do the same for them, or make sure that you call pip3 instead of pip if you want to install any extra package.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux) or [macOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS), the `python` command refers to the built-in Python 2. You need to use the `python3` command to use Python 3.

So running:

```
python3 --version
```

should give you the expected output.

Also, when you want to run your scripts in Python 3, you need to use:

```
python3 myscript.py
```

Answer (score 0):

Both the Python 2.x and Python 3x can exist on a system. On Linux machines the default Python version is Python 2.x.

So if you want to work with Python 2.x, type `python2.7`. Or `python3` otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Installation

1. sudo apt update
2. sudo apt install python3.9

Checking the installation with the python3 --**version** command still returns the old version. To fix this:

1. Create a list of update alternatives. First, add the old version to the list with the command:

`sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.[old-version] 1`

2. Now add the new version:

`sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.9 2`

3. Type the following command to configure the priority status of the versions:

`sudo update-alternatives --config python3`

4. check the default version:

`python3 --version`

***Done***

Comment: Re `sudo apt install python3.9`: This may result in "`E: Unable to locate package python3.9.`". And followed by "`E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'python3.9'.`" and "`E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'python3.9'`"

Comment: What system (incl. version) was it tested on?

Comment: "update-alternatives: error: alternative path /usr/bin/python3.10 doesn't exist" It installed successfully using apt-get install python3.10. yet it's just not there. There must be somebody who has solved this.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, because stack overflow question: [I install python 3.10.0 and in command prompt show me version 2.7.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69612874/i-install-python-3-10-0-and-in-command-prompt-show-me-version-2-7-2) is marked as a duplicate, i cannot answer that question there, so i'm having to answer that question here instead.

**Installing Python 3.10**

To install python 3.10 under ubuntu and make it the default version of python, these are the steps one needs to take:

Firstly, even if you think you've already done these steps (I have), do them again. Previously i had run apt-get install python3.10, and the installer ran to completion and installed python3.10, however the python3.10 binary simply was nowhere to be found on the filesystem. I had to go through and add the resposity deadsnakes/ppa again:

```
apt install -y software-properties-common
add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
apt install python3.10
```

You should now be able to run python3.10 from the command line, check that you can.

```
root@XXX:/home/XXX# python
python            python2           python2.7         python2.7-config  python2-config    python3           python3.10        python3.8         python3.8-config  python3-config    python3-wsdump    python-config     

root@XXX:/home/XXX# python3.10
Python 3.10.12 (main, Jun  7 2023, 12:45:35) [GCC 9.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> exit
Use exit() or Ctrl-D (i.e. EOF) to exit
>>>
```

**Making Python3.10 The Default python3 Version**

At this point, python 3.10 is installed, however if you were to run python3 --version, it would give you the old version of python. In my case this is python 3.8. We now need to instruct python to use the new python 3.10 interpeter and we do this as follows:

Firstly, we add python3.10 to the list:

```
root@XXX:/home/XXX# update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.10 1
```

Then when that's added, we then run the python configuration tool and select python 3.10 by looking through the list and selecting the number. In my case it's option 1.

```
root@XXX:/home/XXX# update-alternatives --config python3
There are 2 choices for the alternative python3 (providing /usr/bin/python3).

  Selection    Path                 Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/bin/python3.8    1         auto mode
  1            /usr/bin/python3.10   1         manual mode
  2            /usr/bin/python3.8    1         manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: 1
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/python3.10 to provide /usr/bin/python3 (python3) in manual mode
```

Now that we've selected the new python version to use, we can check this in the configuration tool:

```
root@XXX:/home/XXX# update-alternatives --config python3
There are 2 choices for the alternative python3 (providing /usr/bin/python3).

  Selection    Path                 Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/bin/python3.10   1         auto mode
* 1            /usr/bin/python3.10   1         manual mode
  2            /usr/bin/python3.8    1         manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

Press Enter to keep the current selection.

Finally, we do a check to make sure that python3 now calls into python3.10...

```
root@XXX:/home/XXX# python3 --version
Python 3.10.12
```

**Installing Python3.10 Virtual Environment**

Optionally, I had to add a python3.10 virtual environment also. Since I'm here I may as well show how this is done also:

```
root@XXX:/home/XXX# apt-get install -y python3-pip
```

Then we add the python3.10-venv:

```
root@XXX:/home/XXX# apt-get install -y python3.10-venv
```

At this point python 3.10 is now installed, with the virtual environment and is setup as the default python3 interpreter.