# I install python 3.10.0 and in command prompt show me version 2.7.2

Tags: python

I after installation python 3.10.0 the latest version in command prompt show me 2.7.2 version but i don't have installed other version in my system in windows

Comment: try 'python3 --version' command

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix "python version are always returned 2.7 instead of 3.7"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56594702/how-to-fix-python-version-are-always-returned-2-7-instead-of-3-7)

Comment: I don't installed python 2.7.2 before

Comment: Did any of the answers solve your problem?

Comment: It's ridiculous that i've followed 5-6 procedures now to install python 3.10 and been on about that many pages on stack overflow trying to figure this out, and nothing has worked. Python3.10 installed on ubuntu successfully. Yet python 3.10 isn't anywhere in any of the paths.

Comment: Also the "question has answers here" is irrelevent it doesn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 3):

If you run `python --version` and it returns "Python 2.7.2", you have it installed and it is the first found python in your current path. That doesn't  mean you don't also have 3.10.0 installed, it just means that it isn't the first one found in your path.

Comment: Also, running `python3` instead of `python` can help. But I'm not on Windows, so idk, checking your path first is a good idea

Answer (score 0):

When installing `Python 3.10`,You need to mark the checkbox `Add Python 3.10 to PATH` That's it.

---

Notice that [Sunsetting Python 2](https://www.python.org/doc/sunset-python-2/)
I also suggest uninstalling Python 2 from Your machine. You can do it (Windows 10) straight through `settings` => `apps`, `search the list` type `Python 2` and run uninstall process. Good Luck ;-)

---

Comment: I marked checkbox  " add python 3.10.0 to path " in ended installation

Comment: I don't have installed on my computer python old version

Comment: Are there any solutions to this problem?